# Unbind() and Off() not clearing the events

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to clear all events inside a div. I have two image buttons btn1 and btn2. For now I need to disable image button click event for my btn1. I have function call onload to set the image url. I'm calling the disable css and then unbind/off. Button looks greyed out, but click event still works.

```
function SetApplicationImage(applType) {
    if (applType.id.indexOf('Dog') > -1) {
        applType.src = "../images/btn1_dog.png";
        $("#btn1").attr('disabled', 'disabled').css('cursor', 'default').fadeTo("fast", .25);
        $('#btn1').off();
        $('#btn1').unbind();
    } else if (applType.id.indexOf('Cat') > -1) {
        applType.src = "../images/btn2_cat.png";
    }
}
```

Comment: how is the event handler added

Comment: can you provide more of your code ?

Comment: show us your html?

Comment: Shouldn't that be `$('#btn1').off("click")` if you are up to unbind the click event?

Answer (score 0):

Is your selector valid ? try this

```
 if ( $( "#btn1" ).length ) {
        console.warn('unbinding...')
        $( "#btn1" ).unbind();     
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to remove the click events with `jQuery`, please ensure that the events are binded with `jQuery` itself. If its an `onclick` `javascript` function, the `off` or `unbind` method will not remove the events. Here is a sample code which binds and unbinds the click events of a button. I hope this will be the solution you are looking for.

```html
<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function ClickFunction(){
            console.log("Clicked");
        }
        function EnableFunction(){
            $('#btn1').off("click", ClickFunction);
            $('#btn1').bind('click', ClickFunction);
            $("#btn1").prop('disabled', false).css('cursor', 'default').fadeTo("fast", 1);
            console.log("Click Event Added");
        }
        function RemoveClickFunction(){
            $('#btn1').off("click", ClickFunction);
            $("#btn1").attr('disabled', 'disabled').css('cursor', 'default').fadeTo("fast", .25);
            console.log("Click Event Removed");
        }
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#btn1').on("click", ClickFunction);
            console.log("Click Event Added");
        })
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <button id="btn1">Click me</button>    
    <button onclick="EnableFunction()" id="btn2">Enable me</button>
    <button onclick="RemoveClickFunction()" id="btn3">Remove Click Function</button>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not unbind any event if you are disabling the button because this will remove the requirement of binding events back when the button is enabled again. However, both `attr()` and `unbind()` should work as follows,

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#btn").attr("disabled", "disabled");

  $("#btnUnbind").click(function() {
    alert("Dont show me");
  });

  $("#btnUnbind").unbind();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Click" />
<input type="button" id="btnUnbind" value="Unbiind" />
```